# Insert XAttribute to existing XElement at specified position

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Here is simplified use case code example for creating element with attributes

```
        XElement element =
            new XElement(
                "Test",
                new XAttribute("Attr1", "value1"),
                new XAttribute("Attr3", "value3")
            );

        element.Add(new XAttribute("Attr2", "value2"));
```

How to achieve that Attr2 is added after Attr1 to produce output like this?

```
        <Test Attr1="value1" Attr2="value2" Attr3="value3" />
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

**Here is the extension method mentioned in accepted answer:**

```
public static void AddAfterSelf(this XAttribute self, XAttribute value)
{
    if (self == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("self");
    if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
    if (self.Parent == null) throw new ArgumentException("Attribute does not belong to any element.");

    XElement e = self.Parent;
    var attributes = new List<XAttribute>(e.Attributes());
    int idx = attributes.IndexOf(self);

    attributes.Insert(idx + 1, value);
    e.RemoveAttributes();
    e.Add(attributes);
}
```

Comment: Not that for compliant XML parser order of attributes should not matter...

Comment: Of course it does not matter for parser. The aim is to create utility that changes files created and modified by other tool and such files are under version control so I want to avoid huge diffs. I might to change the generating code design but if solution exist that will be more elegant...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only way I have found:

```
var attributes = element.Attributes().ToList();
attributes.Insert(1, new XAttribute("Attr2", "value2"));
element.Attributes().Remove();
element.Add(attributes);
```

Comment: Yes that's solution, in mean time I wrote an extension method doing it this way.

Comment: I used this way, just changed `var attributes` with `List<XAttributes>`, plus if i already have an element with some attributes, first I remove all attributes then I reinsert everything, to avoid "duplicate attribute" error.
`List<XAttribute> attributes;
attributes = elem.Attributes().ToList();
                        elem.Attributes().Remove();
                        attributes.Insert(4, new XAttribute("NAME_1", "John") );
                        elem.Add(attributes);`